# Filter list with no modifying the parent component

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular, and I create a generic dropdown component that receives `[options]` as parameter as:

```
   <app-select [control]="profileForm.get('departmentId')" [idAndForAttributes]="'department'" [label]="'Sourced by'"
              [options]="departmentsList"></app-select>
```

The component has an `*ngFor` of the list, and the value displayed is `{{item.Description}}`. This is working as expected.

But now I want to filter the list; I only want to display the list where `departmentsList.IsRecuiter = true`, but I do not want to modify the component because it is generic:

Component TS:

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-select',
  templateUrl: './select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select.component.css']
})
export class SelectComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() control: FormControl;
  @Input() label: string;
  //@Input() placeholder: string = "Select...";
  @Input() options: [];
  @Input() idAndForAttributes: string;
  @Input() customClass: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Component HTML:

```
<div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'invalid': control.invalid && control.touched && control.dirty}">
  <label [attr.for]="idAndForAttributes">{{ label }}:</label>
  <select class="form-control" [ngClass]="customClass" [formControl]="control" [attr.id]="idAndForAttributes">
    <option value="0">- Select -</option>
    <option *ngFor="let item of options" [ngValue]="item.id">{{item.description}}</option>
  </select>
  <ng-container *ngIf="control.dirty && control.touched && control.invalid">
    <div *ngIf="control.errors.required || (control.errors.min && control.value == 0)">
      <small style="color: #c62828;">
        Value is required.
      </small>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

How can I filter the list without modifying the parent component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter the departments in the parent-component and then pass the filtered list to the app-select-component. Your code could then look something like this:

**Parent-Component TS**:

```
departmentsList = [{...}] as Department[]
departmentsWithRecruiters: Department[] = [];

constructor(){
    this.departmentsWithRecruiters = this.departmentsList.filter(d => d.IsRecuiter === true);
}
```

**Parent-Component HTML**:

```
<app-select [control]="profileForm.get('departmentId')" [idAndForAttributes]="'department'" [label]="'Sourced by'"
[options]="departmentsWithRecruiters"></app-select>
```